# How would I draw walls using Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I'm wondering how I would draw walls using pygame, and was wondering whether I would have to screen.blit(tile) for every single tile around the edge, I am hoping there is a simpler way. I only know of the RECT tool to draw sqaures, so I'm unsure.

Here's what I want the game to look like;

[image]

Please note: I'm not looking for the whole code, just some pointers on how to draw the outer wall and tile the backdrop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go over [this tutorial](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/tag/pygame-tutorial). It has walls, among other things

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I haven't looked at it yet, but does it cover map loading from file?

Comment: @jackwilsdon: well, no, but that's an orthogonal problem

Comment: The link to the tutorial is now giving 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do 3D games but want to use Python, I would highly recommend looking into PyOgre3D: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/PyOgre Its a very powerful graphics engine with Python wrappers around all of it's C code.

Pygame is developing a lot and has a lot of potential, but it definitely has a long way to go with 3D games.